# Zend_Db_Table Cascade DELETE doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am developing an application to manage a law office using zend framework 1.10,PHP 5.3 and MySQL, I have made a relationship between two tables and I wanted to do cascade deletion however It doesn't work, I tried all possibilities but nothing...

this is the parent model, refer to all processes

```
<?php
class Application_Model_ProcessosJudicial extends Zend_Db_table {

    protected $_name = "processos_judicial";
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Application_Model_Partes', 'Application_Model_Andamentos');
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Andamento' => array(
            'columns' => array('numero_atual'),
            'refColumns' => array('numero_atual'),
            'refTableClass' => 'Application_Model_Andamentos',
            'onDelete' => self::CASCADE,
            'onUpdate' => self::RESTRICT
        )
    );
```

here is the model which refer to a process's status

```
class Application_Model_Andamentos extends Zend_Db_table {

    protected $_name = "processos_andamentos_judicial";
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Andamento' => array(
            'refTableClass' => 'Application_Model_ProcessosJudicial',
            'refColumns' => array('numero_atual'),
            'columns' => array('numero_atual'),
            'onDelete' => self::CASCADE,
            'onUpdate' => self::RESTRICT
        )
    );
```

When I am gonna delete one process it returns me

> Notice: Undefined index: numero_atual in C:\htdocs\Advocacia\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php on line 1197

it delete the process but all process's status keeps on the datebase.

Anybody can see anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have an index on numero_atual?

Comment: ZF 1.10 does not support PHP 4.3.. did you mean PHP 5.3?

Comment: Your `Application_Model_ProcessosJudicial` class contains `_referenceMap` definition that should only be in the `Application_Model_Andamentos` class. This might be the reason you get the `Undefined index` warning.

Comment: @Billy ONeal numero_atual is a column that exists in both datbase tables
@Stephen J. Fuhry Sorry It's 5.3

Comment: @Vika I changed the refTableClass however still doesn't delete all process's status related to the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding numero_atual to primary, solve the problem.

```
protected $_primary = array("id", "numero_atual");
```